# Second loop is not executing in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

HI I have very strange problem .

Here is my template

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed tablesorter" id="myTable">
             <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Store</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Price(USD)</th>
                            <th>Manufacturer</th>
                            <th>Model</th>
                            <th>Shipping</th>
                            <th>Replacement</th>
                            <th>Details</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                   {% for x in result_amazon|slice:"1" %}     
                    {% if forloop.first  %}                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 <a href="" target="_blank">
                                    <img height="85" width="110" src={% static "images/Amazon-Logo.jpg" %} alt="">
                                 </a>
                             </td>
                             <td><img   src={{x.medium_image_url}} alt=""></td>
                             <td><strong><span class="WebRupee"></span> 
                            {% for y in x.list_price %}
                                             {% if y.price != 'None'%}   
                                                {{y}}
                                            {% endif %}
                             {% endfor %}</strong>
                          </td>
                             <td>{{x.manufacturer}}</td>
                             <td>{{x.model}}</td>
                             <td>Rs. 99</td>
                             <td>Out of Stock</td>
                             <td>
                                 <a href="{{x.detail_page_url}}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary trackinfo" rel="7#@#17205" title="Visit Store" target="_blank">
                                    Visit Store
                                  </a>
                          </td>
                             </tr>
                    {% endif %}    
                  {% endfor %}



             {% for x in result_bestbuy.products %}                                                                                                                                 
                {% if  forloop.first %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="">
                                   <img height="85" width="110"  src={% static "images/bestbuy.gif" %} alt="">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td><img style="height: 168px;" src={{x.image}} alt=""></td>
                            <td><strong><span class="WebRupee"></span>{{x.regularPrice}}</strong></td>
                            <td>{{x.manufacturer}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.modelNumber}}</td>
                            <td>{% if x.freeShipping %}Free Shipping  {% else %}{{x.shippingCost }}{% endif %}</td>
                            <td>14 Days</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{x.url}}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary trackinfo" rel="27#@#17205" title="Visit Store" target="_blank">
                                   Visit Store
                                </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                 {% endif %}
                 {% endfor %}
              {% for x in result_amazon %} 
                {% if not forloop.first %}                 
                        <tr>
                             <td>
                                 <a href=""> </a>
                                   <img height="85" width="110" src={% static "images/Amazon-Logo.jpg" %} alt="">
                                 </a>
                             </td>
                             <td><img   src={{x.medium_image_url}} alt=""></td>

                             <td><strong><span class="WebRupee"></span> 
                                    {% for y in x.list_price %}
                                                     {% if y.price != 'None'%}   
                                                        {{y}}
                                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                 </strong>
                          </td>
                             <td>{{x.manufacturer}}</td>
                             <td>{{x.model}}</td>
                             <td>Rs. 99</td>
                             <td>Out of Stock</td>
                             <td>
                                 <a href="{{x.detail_page_url}}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary trackinfo" rel="7#@#17205" title="Visit Store" target="_blank">
                                    Visit Store
                                 </a>
                          </td>
                             </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                      {% endfor %}

                   {% for x in result_bestbuy.products %} 

                       {% if not  forloop.first %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href=""> </a>
                            </td>
                            <td><img style="height: 168px;" src={{x.image}} alt=""></td>
                            <td><strong><span class="WebRupee"></span>{{x.regularPrice}}</strong></td>
                            <td>{{x.manufacturer}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.modelNumber}}</td>
                            <td>{% if x.freeShipping %}Free Shipping  {% else %}{{x.shippingCost }}{% endif %}</td>
                            <td>14 Days</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{x.url}}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary trackinfo" rel="27#@#17205" title="Visit Store" target="_blank">
                                   Visit Store 
                                </a>
                           </td>
                </tr>
                         {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                      </tbody>
            </table>
```

I am trying to limit the first loop to execute only once initially then rest all has to be executed hence I have applied the `forloop.first`  condition .

My simple question is `"Why the third loop(result_amazon) is not printing any data"` (There are lot many data present in the result_amazon).

Please help me out what might I am doing wrong here .

Comment: Your code and question is confusing. Fix indent of your code and highlight/add comment in template about which loop is misbehaving.

Comment: @Rohan  PLease see the formatted code

Comment: Try dumping `result_amazon` as is and its length before that `for` loop.

Comment: what do you mean by dumping when I am printing result_amazon it prints object in template

Comment: How are you viewing the data - it could be something simple like mis-matched html tags, causing your web-browser to render the page incorrectly (although I can't initially spot anything wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Check the console of your browser and look for any errors in your html code.